# Restricting image sizes in MailChimp that works across all email clients

Tags: mailchimp

In a MailChimp template I have some editable image blocks whereby the user uploads new images for each campaign.

The HTML code has specific sizes for the images, and when viewing in MailChimp everything seems ok.

For each new campaign, typically our users would upload larger images than the fixed pixel size (which is understandable), and assume these would be scaled down. However certain email clients refuse to obey the inline CSS and HTML in the code, and show the images at a larger size.

The only way we can get it to work is by clicking Settings on each image and specifying the proportions.

Does this really need to be done each time?  I'm sure I'm not missing anything but this seems really over-complicated.

Comment: OMG totally missed that settings tab, let me buy you a beer. Could not believe MailChimp was stripping the image dimensions by default, and Outlook was crying as a result!